# How do I segue through dates?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Imagine each view on the screen is to show some information about that particular day.  Swiping right advances the date by one day, swiping left shows yesterday's data.

I've managed to achieve this by capturing the swipe gesture and updating the data on the screen, but I don't get the swipe animation.  I'm guessing the proper way to do this is to segue the view controller to itself and update instead but I'm not sure.  Can anyone advise on the proper way to do this?

Comment: I think it is appropriate to add a child VC as the VC whose view handle the animation. And remove it after the animation.

Comment: Don't segue. Animate. Animate the view off the screen one way, then update code, then animate it back on from the other side.

Comment: Ok that sounds good - is there a simple example of that somewhere please?

Comment: are you looking something like this?
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=carousel

I assume your question not about DATA (day or time or whatever... it's a content) and what you are trying to achieve is - aka "carousel" or pagination, so you can easy get something already written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a block like this for each direction. This one is for Swipe Right (go back). The other direction is reversed.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(0.1), animations: {
            //swipes view off screen
            self.calView.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        })
        UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(0), delay: NSTimeInterval(0.1), options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
            //jumps to other side
            self.calView.frame.origin.x = -self.view.frame.width
            }, completion: { _ in
                //reload data, subtract one, whatever
                self.setCurrentDate()
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })
        UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(0.1), delay: NSTimeInterval(0.2), options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
            //swipes back to center
            self.calView.frame.origin.x = 0
            }, completion: nil)
```